# Externalize app version info

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I want my app's preloader to display version/build info that I have in an XML file. Obviously, the preloader can't pick it up because it waits for XML file to load. Is there another approach that I can use to externalize my version/build info and ensure it's in my app early?

Any tips are helpful and very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically use [compiler constants](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_21.html) for this data, as it's available at build time, and can be easily baked into the app.

```
-define+=CONFIG::VERSION "1.0.1-a"

private static const version:String = CONFIG::VERSION;


<s:Label text="{version}" />
```